# Spring boot JPA/Hibernate. NoSuchElementException on startup

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Hope someone here can help me out. I'm having the worst sort of problem. One that only happens sometimes and never when I run things locally.

I have a spring boot service that's deployed in a kubernetes cluster. When I run it locally against the production database, everything always works. But when started inside k8s, it sometimes fails with NoSuchElementException. When this happens, it's often enough to change a word in a log line, rebuild and redeploy. It appears to be something that's done during the build phase because when the error happens and the k8s pod tries to start again and again, it always fails. So the same container image will either always work or always fail when starting up.

This started happening around the time when I connected Invoice with PropertyKey and User to Customer. Before that, everything was fine. The entities in question are User, ApiUser, Customer, Invoice, InvoiceLine and PropertyKey.  The connection between them is as follows:

```
@Entity
public User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
…
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true )
    private List<Customer> customers;
}

@Entity
public Customer {
    @Id
    private Long customerId;
…
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private User user;
...
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany( mappedBy = "customer" )
    private List<Invoice> invoices;
}

@Entity
public class Invoice
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
    private Long id;
…
    @OneToMany( mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL )
    List<InvoiceLine> lines;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne( cascade = CascadeType.ALL )
    @JoinColumn( name = "customer_id" )
    //@Transient
    private Customer customer;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn( name = "prop_id", referencedColumnName = "propId" )
    private PropertyKey propertyKey;
…
}

@Entity
public InvoiceLine {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
    private Long id;
…
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    private Invoice parent;
…
}

@Entity
public class PropertyKey {
    @Id
    private Long propId;
…
    @JsonIgnore
    //@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER )
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn( name = "api_user" )
    private ApiUser apiUser;

…
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany( mappedBy = "propertyKey" )
    private List<Invoice> invoices;
...
}

@Entity
public class ApiUser {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
…
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "apiUser" )
    //@Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    private List<PropertyKey> propertyKeys;
…
}
```

I have left some comments in place. E.g. in the Invoice class, Customer used to be a transient property.

The exact stacktrace I get is this:

```
05.08.2020 14:26:24.258 [ERROR] SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
    at is.godo.server.property.server.PropertyServer.main(PropertyServer.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher.main(WarLauncher.java:58)
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: null
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:862)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.TableBinder.linkJoinColumnWithValueOverridingNameIfImplicit(TableBinder.java:713)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.PkDrivenByDefaultMapsIdSecondPass.doSecondPass(PkDrivenByDefaultMapsIdSecondPass.java:37)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1684)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1641)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1202)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1233)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792)
    ... 24 common frames omitted
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. There are some older entity relations that I'm not showing in the code but I could add them if three's nothing odd in what I have included.

Thanks a lot!
Gísli

Comment: You have forgot the @Entity annotation on last three classes. Add it and then share your experience.

Comment: I didn't forget them. I was writing the class names up since I changed them slightly for this post. But thanks, I will add the @Entity annotations so that's clear.